# How to use the database from a BackgroundService in .NET Web API

Tags: c#, .net, webapi

I am building a microservice which is supposed to send periodical notifications through various means.

To process the notifications and triggers I intend to use a BackgroundService which will look into database, call appropriate service based on notification type and mark into the database the notification as being sent.

How can I access the database from the background service in a safe way, not having concurrency issues?

Is it enough to inject IServiceProvider and create a scope?

```
public class MyBackgroundService : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

    public MyBackgroundService(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        await DoWorkAsync(stoppingToken);
    }

    private async Task DoWorkAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {

        using (IServiceScope scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope())
        {
            IRepository<Notification> notificationRepository =
                scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IRepository<Notification>>();
            IRepository<NotificationLog> notificationLogRepository =
                scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IRepository<NotificationLog>>();
            IUnitOfWork unitOfWork = 
                scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IUnitOfWork>();

                
            while(true)
            {
                 if(stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
                 {
                     return;
                 }

                var list = await notificationRepository.GetAll();
                .....................................
                await notificationLogRepository.Add(...);
                await unitOfWork.Commit();
            }
        }
    }

    public override async Task StopAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {

        await base.StopAsync(stoppingToken);
    }
}
```

Comment: What does your code do? If you load records from one table only to copy them to another, an `INSERT Table2 (...) SELECT ... FROM Table1` would be far faster because it wouldn't have to load the data to the client and send it back

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it enough to inject IServiceProvider and create a scope?

Yes.

While you *can* create a single scope for your entire background worker's lifetime, you also can create a scope per "invocation" - in this case, you could create a new scope each time the timer goes off. That way, if there's ever a situation where the next one starts before the current one completes, the two invocations will be guaranteed to have different scopes.

If your "timer" is just doing an `await Task.Delay`, though, then there's no possibility of overlapping invocations and separate scopes aren't necessary. Some people prefer them anyway, since "invocation" and "scope" conceptually go well together.